# Rails cache curly braces block syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

Anyone know why I get a syntax error when I try to use curly braces block syntax for `Rails.cache.fetch`

This errors out with error (syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) )

```
Rails.cache.fetch "person/#{id}" { find(id) }
```

The following works:

```
Rails.cache.fetch "person/#{id}" do
  find(id)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because {} has different precedence than do end. In the first expression they are tied to the "person/#{id}" part of the expression.

So your first example is similar to:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("person/#{id}" { find(id) })
```

while the second is:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("person/#{id}") { find(id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

the short block needs () before to recognise the syntax it should look something like

```
Rails.cache.fetch("person/#{id}") { find(id) }
```